# Login page not functioning

Tags: php

When I open the login page for the first time, even if I use correct username and password, the login page is not being redirected to home page. But on the second login it is properly being redirected to home page. The code of login.php  looks like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['login_user'] = false;
?>
```

Rest of login.php is simple html and the login form data is sent to validate.php
where validate.php looks like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
    $username="";
    $password="";
    $usernameErr=""; 
    $passwordErr="";
    $empty=false;
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = false;
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(empty($_POST['username']))
        {
            $empty=true;
            $usernameErr="Username is empty. Please try again";
        }
        else 
            {
                $username=$_POST['username'];
            }
        if(empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $empty=true;
            $passwordErr="Password is empty. Please try again";
        }
        else 
            {
                $password=$_POST['password'];
            }
        if(!$empty)
        {
            $servername="myxor.in.mysql";
            $dbusername="myxor_in";
            $dbpassword="srikanth177";
            $dbname="myxor_in";
            $conn=new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
            if($conn->connect_error) 
            {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            $sql = "SELECT firstname,package,username,password FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if (($result->num_rows) > 0) 
            {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                if($username === $row['username']) 
                    {
                        if($password === $row['password'])
                        {
                            $_SESSION['fname'] = $row['firstname'];
                            $_SESSION['pack'] = $row['package'];
                            //$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
                            $_SESSION['login_user'] = true;
                            header('Location: http://www.myxor.in/home.php');
                            exit;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $passwordErr = "Invalid Password. Please Try Again";
                        }
                    }
            } else
            {
                $usernameErr = "Invalid Username. Please Try Again";
            }
        }
    }
    else echo "submit not set";
    echo $usernameErr;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $passwordErr;
?>
```

Any suggestions why the login page is not functioning for the first time (Note that when I login second time its being properly redirected to required home.php)

Comment: may be there is some issue in set session.
Pl. check that when second time come on that login page then session is enable or not?

Comment: firstly you should check $_SESSION['login_user'] is true if yes then redirect it to home.php

Comment: Just above where you set the $_SESSION['login_user'] to true you should echo something out as a test to see if it's actually getting to this point. Try something like: `echo "Got to here #1";` You'll also need to place a temporary `exit;` before your redirect as well otherwise you won't see the message show up.  If you don't see the "Got to here #1" message, place another message in a different spot in your script and see if that one shows up. This is basic error testing to narrow down which parts of your script are running. If you need to see the contents of a variable echo those out as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should print your session variables on the login page. Something like this:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

So that when you enter the login information and are not redirected on the first try, you will see if the values are being set. That's the first step to take. Then you will have a better idea of what you need to change in your files.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username="";
    $password="";
    $usernameErr=""; 
    $passwordErr="";
    $empty=false;
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = false;
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(empty($_POST['username']))
        {
            $empty=true;
            $usernameErr="Username is empty. Please try again";
        }
        else 
        {
            $username=$_POST['username'];
        }
        if(empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            $empty=true;
            $passwordErr="Password is empty. Please try again";
        }
        else 
        {
            $password=$_POST['password'];
        }
        if(!$empty)
        {
            $servername="myxor.in.mysql";
            $dbusername="myxor_in";
            $dbpassword="srikanth177";
            $dbname="myxor_in";
            $conn=new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
            if($conn->connect_error) 
            {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            $sql = "SELECT firstname,package,username,password FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if (($result->num_rows) > 0) 
            {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                if($username == $row['username']) 
                    {
                        if($password == $row['password'])
                        {
                            $_SESSION['fname'] = $row['firstname'];
                            $_SESSION['pack'] = $row['package'];
                            //$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
                            $_SESSION['login_user'] = true;
                            header('Location: http://www.myxor.in/home.php');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $passwordErr = "Invalid Password. Please Try Again";
                        }
                    }
            } else
            {
                $usernameErr = "Invalid Username. Please Try Again";
            }
        }
    }
    else echo "submit not set";
    echo $usernameErr;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $passwordErr;
?>
```